# Logging in Without MyOpenID

Tags: support, login, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a notification on stackoverflow that someone contacted me about work, with the title *careers message*.

When I click on this notification, I am taken to a page on careers.stackoverflow.com, and prompted to log in.

However, my log in has always been with myopenid, which has apparently shut down.

I was able to quickly and easily log in using my Facebook account instead. There's just one problem: it appears I'm now logged in to a brand new account. I have no access to my profile or the message that was apparently sent to me.

How do I get my old account back?

Comment: The answers to [this other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-shuts-down-february-1-2014-add-an-alternative-login-method-to-your-ac) might help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form to request that the accounts be merged.

Then once that's done you can remove the MyOpenID from the list of logins.

It would also be useful to add a second login (Google?) to your account in case there are problems with the primary one you have chosen.

Comment: I was actually able to access the old account by logging in with Google. I'm not sure exactly why that is--I don't recall using Google before. It's a little confusing but I got my data back. I will use the contact link to try and get the two accounts merged.

Comment: @JonathanWood as a side note, this is why, if you own a domain name, or really if you control a webpage anywhere, it it's good to use OpenID delegation. You can change providers without changing identities.

Comment: Note that Google's shutting down its OpenID provider in 2015, so relying on Google isn't a good idea.

Comment: I believe SO has already migrated to Google's new authentication mechanism based on OpenID Connect and hopefully implemented a migration strategy as documented in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: @jamessan: Thanks, but that's why this seems less than ideal. Particularly with a site like careers.stackexchange.com, users may only need to visit it once every several years. They come back, and they've lost their login. HansZ: I hope that is correct.